# How do I change php code to put a static url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have code to create a review email, using the product the customer ordered, a photo of it and a link to the review part of the product page. The code looks like this -

```
<tbody>
<?php $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap><?php echo $product->get_image($size = 'shop_thumbnail'); ?></td>
            <td nowrap><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?> </td>
            <td nowrap><a href="<?php echo $url = get_permalink($product->id).'#reviews'; ?>" style="background-color: #000; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px;">REVIEW NOW</a></td>
        </tr>
<?php                                                                   }
?>
</tbody>
```

I want to change the link on the 'review now' box to be a static link. I've tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
<a href="<?php echo $url = "www.google.com" ?>" style="background-color: #000; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px;">REVIEW NOW</a>
```

Comment: The *href* attribute of the link should be a valid URL so `www.google.com` has to be replaced by `https://www.google.com` or whatever. You need to add the protocol. If it's static then no PHP tags are needed to create it so just put `<a href="https://www.your-domain.com/..." style="...." ...`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use php for static url. You can add it directly in href attribute of anchor tag.
`<a href="https://www.google.com/" style="background-color: #000; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px;">REVIEW NOW</a>`